# angular-ui dropdown-toggle [object Object] has no method parent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I've got a problem employing angular-ui Bootstrap in my project. Namely dropdown directive.

By now i have HTML that is just a copy-paste from the examples:

```
<ul>
 <li class="dropdown">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle"> Drop!</a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li> one </li>
     <li> two </li>
   </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

When Angular compiles HTML this error is thrown for each dropdown i have on the page:

```
TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'parent'
at link (http://localhost:3000/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.js:1316:15) 
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:6124:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:5536:15)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:5539:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:5539:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:5539:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:5539:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:5444:30)
at boundTranscludeFn (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:5555:21)
at controllersBoundTransclude (http://localhost:3000/vendor/angular/angular.js:6145:18) <a class="dropdown-toggle">
```

This line binds click event on a.dropdown-toggle parent (that is li.dropdown obviously).

What am i doing wrong? I've lost more than three hours trying to solve this and still have no idea what can cause this error.

p.s. HTML is compiled from Jade, and i use Bootstrap 3, but i hope that's not the point this time.

UPD: as Nix asked, i include head and app.js

```
head
  title= title
  meta(charset='utf-8')
  meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')
  link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/client/main.css')

  script(src='/vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js', type='text/javascript')
  script(src='/vendor/angular/angular.js', type='application/javascript')
  script(src='/vendor/angular/angular-route.js', type='application/javascript')
  script(src='/vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.7.0.js', type='text/javascript')

  script(src='/angular/client/app.js', type='text/javascript')
  script(src='/angular/client/menu/controllers.js', type='text/javascript')
  //a lot of other app stuff...
```

it's app.js

```
var app = angular.module('clientApp',[
  'ngRoute',
  'menuControllers'
]);
```

it's menu controllers

```
var menu = angular.module('menuControllers', [
  'sharedModels',
  'ui.bootstrap'
]);
menu.controller('menuCtrl', ['$scope', 'categoriesModel', 'subcategoriesModel', menuCtrl]);
```

and the full source of menu.jade. it's included to body ng-app='clientApp'

```
div.container(ng-controller='menuCtrl')
  div(ng-repeat='cat in categoriesModel')
    div.btn-group
      a.btn.btn-default(href='#!/category/{{cat._id}}') {{cat.name}}
      ul
        li.dropdown
          a.dropdown-toggle Dropdown
          ul.dropdown-menu(ng-repeat='subcat in subcategoriesModel')
            li: a(ng-href='#!/subcategories/{{subcat._id}}') {{subcat.name}}
```

Comment: Throw a fiddle at this question, and it will be answered within minutes.  Looks like U have an object vs a jQuery selector but need some type of JS to figure it out.

Comment: Well. it works it plunker and does not throw any error. http://plnkr.co/edit/ggNFUHDaJ6ZQLVRO66FJ

Comment: :)  sometimes trying to reproduce the problem helps us fix the problem. Post some of your code (head tag) and js(where you setup angular).

Comment: I've updated the topic. To say the truth, it seems that i'd better rewrite this from scratch.

Comment: I'm searching for it but dont have much luck.  Have you validated that you can browse to /vendor/jquery-1.10.2.min.js  (i noticed your plunkr did not include it).

Comment: Sure, each .js file is loaded into the browser and all dependencies are satisfied (at least no injection error is thrown). Actually, i do not use JQuery along with Angular, it was one of efforts to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your plunkr doesn't match the jade(give me a broken plunkr and i can fix it).  I know you are trying to target "dropdown" directive but sometimes there is some black magic that happens within angular that you might not think about.  For instance the btn-group class could be a directive that is firing and wrecking shop.  Please update the fiddle to match your jade, also make sure you call out any other angular OTS libraries that you are including in your project.

Shot in the dark:

Change:

```
ul.dropdown-menu(ng-repeat='subcat in subcategoriesModel')
    li: a(ng-href='#!/subcategories/{{subcat._id}}') {{subcat.name}}
```

to:

```
ul.dropdown-menu
    li(ng-repeat='subcat in subcategoriesModel'): a(ng-href='#!/subcategories/{{subcat._id}}') {{subcat.name}}
```

Comment: It seems to be some kind of black magic. http://plnkr.co/edit/ggNFUHDaJ6ZQLVRO66FJ No "parent()" error. Just the content on the dropdown list affected. Anyway, by now i have completely rewritten that module and it works! Still have no idea what have caused that error...